Is there a way to debug entity-framework with access to code?
I am a dev' op's and am suspicious the EE mem caching in our app isn't working right.
So I can triage it, is there a way to debug it or affect what is it and is not being cached but without access to the code, everything I have found online so far refers to code :-(
Looked online so far refers to code changes rather than how to do in place debugging (by changing a config file for example)
